# How do I show $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}6x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - 4\cos(\frac{1}{x}) + \frac{1}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ doesn't exist?

Tags: limits

So I have this function and I need to prove it is not continuous on $0$.

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}6x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - 4\cos(\frac{1}{x}) + \frac{1}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

But I don't know how to do it. I know that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ don't exist but how can I be sure there aren't any trigonometric identities I don't know (even if it is very unlikely to happen) that would simplify that function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
 f(x) = 6x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
        -4 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
        + \frac{1}{x} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
and consider the sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with
$$
 x_n = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi}
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 y_n = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + (2n+1)\pi}
 \quad
 \text{for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$}.
$$
If $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists then so do $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n)$ and all three limits are equal. But
$$
 f(x_n) = 6x_n+\frac{1}{x_n} \to \infty
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 f(y_n) = -6y_n-\frac{1}{y_n} \to -\infty
 \quad
 \text{as $n \to \infty$}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$6x\sin(\frac1x)$ and $5\cos(\frac1x)$ are both bounded around $0$, while $\frac1x\sin(\frac1x)$ is not. That means the whole function is also not bounded around $0$.